# React Context - dispatch from a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have to call dispatch (Context, not Redux) in a function, but I am not able to do this. (`Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`)

Is there a way to run hooks (or only `dispatch`) inside a function called from a component?
I can do this using Redux (`store.dispatch(...)`), but I have no idea how to do this with React Context.

Example function:

```
function someAction() {
  const { dispatch } = React.useContext(SomeContext);
  dispatch({
    type: "ACTION_NAME",
  });
}
```

I am trying to call that function directly from a component:

```
<button onClick={() => someAction()}>Click me</button>
```

Sure, I can pass `dispatch`, but I want to avoid this because the function will be shared and it should be simple.

```
<button onClick={() => someAction(dispatch)}>Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use hooks in components or other hooks, but you can use the return value of hooks inside other functions. Extract the `useContext` from the function, and use the returned `dispatch`:

```
const Component = () => {
  const { dispatch } = React.useContext(SomeContext);

  function someAction() {
    dispatch({
      type: "ACTION_NAME",
    });
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={someAction}>Click me</button>
  );
};
```

I would create a custom hook that returns the action function, and use it in the component, to make it less clunky and more reusable:

```
const useAction = () => {
  const { dispatch } = React.useContext(SomeContext);
  
  return () => dispatch({
    type: "ACTION_NAME",
  });
};
```

Usage:

```
const Component = () => {
  const someAction = useAction();
  
  return (
    <button onClick={someAction}>Click me</button>
  );
};
```